# Can't write or read CBPeripheral | CBMutableCharacteristic

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I'm tying to connect to a bluetooth hardware, but I can't get a notification, when a value is updated, and read to read, here's my code :

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {

    guard peripheral == self.peripheral && error == nil else {
        return
    }

    if let characteristics = service.characteristics {
        for characteristic in characteristics {
            if characteristic.UUID == QuadrarCharacteristicUUID {
                if let peripheral = self.peripheral {
                    self.quadrarCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: QuadrarCharacteristicUUID,
                        properties: [.Read, .Write, .Notify],
                        value: nil,
                        permissions: [.Readable, .Writeable])
                    self.quadrarCharacteristic?.descriptors = characteristic.descriptors
                    peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: self.quadrarCharacteristic!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and when I'm writing :

```
 func writeBytes() {
           self.quadrarCharacteristic!.service.peripheral.writeValue(self.bytesToWriteArray[self.senderCounter], 
            forCharacteristic: self.quadrarCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
    }
```

I know, that even writing is not working because the

```
 func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?)
```

is not being called...
but if I use only the

```
var quadrarCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?
```

and try to write it, as a non CBMutableCharacteristic, it works, but I can't get the notification to work...

Answer (score 3):

You don't create a new `CBMutableCharacteristic` when you are acting as a central, you simply use the `CBCharacteristic` objects that are given to you in `didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService` -

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {

    guard peripheral == self.peripheral && error == nil else {
        return
    }

    if let characteristics = service.characteristics {
        for characteristic in characteristics {
            if characteristic.UUID == QuadrarCharacteristicUUID {
                self.quadrarCharacteristic=charateristic
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: self.quadrarCharacteristic!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you need to confirm that your characteristic supports notification.